# Detect shapes in image using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have little experience using Python and its libraries, and I need to develop a method to detect and count squares, triangles and circles from an image. The problem is, these shapes could be overlayed on top of each other. Here's an example:

[A train made out of trigonometric shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChDqE.jpg)

With this particular image, there are two problems:

- The wheels are composed of 10 circles in total, five big ones and another five circles inside each one of them, but my code somehow detects 19 circles in total.
- There are quadrilateral shapes that are not fully straight in all sides, because of the wheels overlaying them.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('trem.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
    threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

i = 0

shapes = dict()
triangle = quadrilateral = circle = 0

for contour in contours:

    if i == 0:
        i = 1
        continue

    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(
        contour, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)

    cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)

    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    if M['m00'] != 0.0:
        x = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
        y = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])

    if len(approx) == 3:
        triangle += 1
        shapes.update({'Triangle': triangle})

    elif len(approx) == 4:
        quadrilateral += 1
        shapes.update({'Quadrilateral': quadrilateral})
    else:
        circle += 1
        shapes.update({'Circle': circle})

cv2.imshow('shapes', img)
print(shapes)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output line is: `{'Circle': 19, 'Quadrilateral': 5, 'Triangle': 2}`

The correct answer should be: `{'Circle': 10, 'Quadrilateral': 6, 'Triangle': 2}`

The only shape that seems to be correctly detected is the triangle. Can someone help me in this? Is there another way to do this without using OpenCV? I know this would be very complicated, but it would be preferable. I am able to detect contours without OpenCV, but how can I know something is a circle, or square?

Comment: maybe [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) can handle this problem?

Comment: That's actually very simple and easy to apply... The thing is, I wanted to know how to do this myself, preferably without using libraries like OpenCV. With edge detection algorithms and such.